# Grading for an exam using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make an exam using JavaScript.

So,I have this HTML page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<script>
function myf() {
    var z=0;
    var x=document.getElementById('1');
    var y=document.getElementById('2');
    var n=document.getElementById('3');
if (x.checked==true){
    z=z+1;
  }
if (y.checked==true){
    z=z+1;
  }
if (n.checked==true){
   z=z+1;
  }
alert(z);

}

</script>
<body>
 <p>qs_1</p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="1" />
  <input type="checkbox"   />
  <input type="checkbox"   />
  <input type="checkbox"   />
<br>
 <p>qs_2</p><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="2" />
  <input type="checkbox"   />
  <input type="checkbox"   />
  <input type="checkbox"   />
<br>
 <p>qs_3</p><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="3" />
  <input type="checkbox"   />
  <input type="checkbox"   />
  <input type="checkbox"   />
<br>
 <p>dewdqwdew</p><br>
  <input type="button" onClick="myf ();" value="check now!" />
</body>
</html>
```

This code shows the correct answers but I want it to show:

1. number of correct answers
2. number of false answers
3. explanation(I mean  to alert in code), for example:

   - question 1 is correct
   - question 2 is not correct
   - question 3 is correct
     I will appreciate any help!

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff. You might want to consult an introductory text on JavaScript. (I've heard [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Learn/JavaScript) are good.)

Comment: thanks for your answer,but would you guide me more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myf() {
var z = 0;
var x = document.getElementById('1');
var y = document.getElementById('2');
var n = document.getElementById('3');

if (x.checked == true) {
    z = z + 1;
    alert("question 1 Correct");
} else(alert("question 1 incorrect"));

if (y.checked == true) {
    z = z + 1;
    alert("question 2 Correct");
} else(alert("question 2 incorrect"));

if (n.checked == true) {
    z = z + 1;
    alert("question 3 Correct");
} else(alert("question 3 incorrect"));
```

}

Pretty simple, if this is what you're looking for, just if else's. You were nearly there.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i didn't mean this exactly!I want it to alert when user click on the button.Please take a look at code again

Comment: It's not exactly what I want.you know;when user clicks on button;we have several messages but I want it to show all information in one message!and your code has a problem too!,it start counting false answers from 9!!!

Comment: OK,that's not my problem!my real problem are messages!I want this code to show all information in one message box.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5ujudx62/3/ - simple, i'll let you sort out the configuration / style.